# Using invalidate table in a prepared statement

Tags: java, hive, sonarqube, impala

I'm attempting to call:
"invalidate metadata " + table_name

If I execute the query directly, I fall foul of a sonarqube rule that states that the code is vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack. (It isn't, as I've validated the table name elsewhere.)

```
    String query = "invalidate metadata " + table;
    try (Connection con = hiveConnectionFactory.getConnection(hiveConnDetailsHelperBean)) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.execute();
            LOGGER.debug("metadata invalidated " + table);
        }
    } catch (SQLException | MoLiConnectionException e) {
        String errorMessage = "Error Running Query: "+ query;
        throw new MoLiConnectionException(errorMessage, e);
    }
```

If I attempt to use a prepared statement as suggested by SonarQube I get an exception:

```
    String query = "invalidate metadata ?";
    try (Connection con = hiveConnectionFactory.getConnection(hiveConnDetailsHelperBean)) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.setString(1, table);
            stmt.execute();
            LOGGER.debug("metadata invalidated " + table);
        }
    } catch (SQLException | MoLiConnectionException e) {
        String errorMessage = "Error Running Query: "+ query;
        throw new MoLiConnectionException(errorMessage, e);
    }

AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
invalidate metadata 'dru_jhutc.time_test'
                    ^
Encountered: STRING LITERAL
Expected: DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

My question is: How can I use a prepared statement to get around the sonarqube rule?

Comment: Does `table` include the single quotes around the table name or were they added by the `PerparedStatement`? I think you cannot use the `?` for a table name, only for parameters used in conditions, like in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The single quotes appear to have been added by the prepared statement.

Comment: Also, I think you are right about the ? as well, but it seems odd that SonarQube flagged it up, and told me to do it that way, so I thought I would ask here, before giving up on the idea

Comment: That's what I thought... You cannot parametrize tables or fields but values only.

Comment: Most likely, SonarQube has detected a `String` called `query` and a concatenation on it. That might have caused the warning. You know it better, you have validated the table names somewhere else. SonarQube just checks for common patterns that often lead to weaknesses.